# Virtuemart displaying

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I want to know if someone know how to display a virtuemart category products into another page like use a shortcode or something like that to display a list of product from one category into another page.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with a module.
The default "virtuemart products" module has an option to select from which category you will get the products.

If you want to put them inside an article, you could load your module with loadposition. A complete tutorial how you could do that is: [How do you put a module inside an article?](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article%3F)

Comment: is there any way to load the "virtuemart products" module into the page two times i have blank page when i do it any suggestions?

Comment: If you can't do it with loadmodule you could try loadposition.
You have to add two new positions to "templates/your_template_name/templateDetails.xml" and then put one module in each position.
In your article you will load the two positions as: {loadposition myposition}